# Deciding a coding strategy, is there a simpler way?

Tags: php, sql

I'm looking for help more on strategy than specific code. So please don't take this as a request to write large pieces of the code for me. I need to write it in PHP and it needs to do the following:

First, I need the user to make a selection of locations from a list, the script will then display a stored distance between those two locations.

For this my initial idea is create a database, have a table for each place, and then have a row for each other place in said table. So for instance of they choose "LA" and "Seattle", it will grab the "LA" table, then output the value for the "Seattle" cell. The only problem I can think for this, is that it has a lot of tables, and it would make it really difficult to add new places, because not only do you have to add a new table for that place, but also a new row in all the other tables.

Is there a better way to approach this?

I know there is some functionality that allows you to import excel spreadsheets, but I am not familiar with it, or how easy it would be to index that data for recalling specific cells.

Appreciate the help!

Comment: Why not a table for the places and a table for the distances (place1, place2, dist) ?

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_foreignkey.asp

Comment: Thanks, that's a good idea too, and might get rid of some of the redundancy I had in my solution as well as Brad's. I will play around with both.

Comment: @ElSergio It's the same idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would absolutely not store your data in the way that you are proposing.  That would require a table with thousands of columns.

If you really are dealing with geographic areas, and you can rely on the Earth being approximated as a perfectly round sphere, just store the coordinates of areas and calculate the distance on the fly.

If you need to factor in other things such as transit transfer points or other arbitrary distance calculations, store the data in a table with the columns like this:

- id
- startLocationId
- endLocationId
- distance

You can have an "locations" table that has all the attributes of each area:

- id
- cityName
- stateName
- *etc.*

Comment: Thanks for your quick response, I should have added, that these are not actually real places on earth, it is for a game. Presently there are only 18 locations, but there could be as many as 100 at some future point in time, So coordinates would not work (but is a great idea!).

So if I understand your second suggestion, I would basically have a row for each location combination, correct?

Comment: @ElSergio That is correct.